# How to increase user engagement rate?

Tags: site-growth, user-engagement

I have for the past month been working hard on a new project for myself about learning Korean. Writing the blog and sharing everything I do, is a real blast. However, as you might imagine, a response now and then would be awesome, but I have a severe lack of user engagement

I get the odd like and once in a while I get a comment on Facebook, but not something realy substantial that culminates in a talk between a reader and myself.

What would be the best strategies to promote user engagement? 
How can I get a community feel started?

I tried a lot of things, but perhaps I am just missing something.

Comment: Could you [edit] in something about what you've tried already?  Where do your current readers come from?  Did you have an existing audience and have started blogging about a new topic, or is this a whole new project?  Approximately how many followers do you have now?

Comment: Question number one to ask yourself: *What's in it for them?* It's great that you share your enthusiasm, but is that in itself enough enrollment for your readers to participate?

Comment: And one of the most important rules in social media marketing is: **Ask for** participation. Ask questions, present challenges. Are you doing that?

Comment: This question is too general. Community engagement is central to community building. You need to narrow this question to a specific context or approach you tried. Per your question, maybe "how can I get more comments on my blog posted to my Facebook community page?" Here is an example of a more specific question: http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/what-are-best-practices-for-creating-engaging-experience-in-a-forum-based-commun

Comment: I'm not so sure you have a reader engagement problem.  If nobody is commenting... how do you know you have any readers?  Is your problem that your audience doesn't engage with you, or is your problem that you don't have an audience?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, Facebook has a low engagement rate for community building, particularly if what you're sharing is reading content.

Some strategies you might try to boost community engagement in no particular order:

- Create other kinds of content (videos, podcasts, more photos).
- Share on other platforms like Instagram, Twitter, Tumblr, Google+, Reddit, Youtube
- Hold an AMA (Ask Me Anything) on Reddit (https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA)
- Ask some of your friends nicely in real life to interact with your content to get the ball rolling
- Pay for advertising
- Pay a freelancer to spice up your content